# Dynamic methods won't work in-app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still in the learning phase of Ruby and RoR, but I've already encountered a problem.
I've created a scaffold called Users with fields "name" and "password".
Later on, I also added more fields such as "pin" and "salt".

Now, while User.find_by_name and find_by_password work perfectly fine, for some reason, find_by_pin doesn't seem to work. I've tried googling a bit but found nothing.

<s>I also tried the same method in the ruby console (rails console) and for some reason, it works perfectly fine there - it returns the correct data just as expected.</s>

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

As somebody stated in the comments, let's say I'm using this code: (yes, cookies[:pin] is set)

```
def get_user
    user = User.find_by_pin(cookies[:pin])
    if user.pin == cookies[:pin]
        'yes'
    end
end
```

and later I do this:

```
<%= get_user %>
```

it returns this:

```
undefined method `pin' for nil:NilClass
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried this:

```
def get_user

    user = User.find_by_name('Crembo')
    user.pin  # returns 753e345a113471a6775e242f444704fe

    user = User.find_by_pin(user.pin)
    if user.nil?
        'is nil'
    else
        'exists'
    end
end
```

and it returns 'is nil'. How does that make sense?

To extend that,

```
def pin_check
    user = User.find_by_name('Crembo')

    if user.pin == cookies[:pin]
        'true'
    else
        'false'
    end
end
```

returns true.

**EDIT 3:**

As asked in the comments, my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts

    validates_uniqueness_of :name

    def password_matches?(password_to_match)
        self.password == Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(password_to_match)
    end
end
```

Comment: `rake db:migrate` should help you.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use `find_by_pin`? You need to elaborate on how they "don't seem to work".

Comment: Did that around 10 times by now, still nothing. Added an explanation as James wanted.

Comment: seems like you haven't this user with such pin

Comment: Ok, apparently, I am blind, because find_by_pin doesn't work in rails console, just in-app... And I do have such a user with such a pin. I'm not very smart, but not that stupid.

Comment: If you use the bang version (`User.find_by_pin! cookies[:pin]`) you'll most likely see that you *don't* have a user with that pin. Bang versions of finder methods will raise errors instead of returning nil. You should verify that `cookies[:pin]` actually contains the correct value.

Comment: I tried that, it says `Couldn't find User with pin = 753e345a113471a6775e242f444704fe`, but if you checked my edit, you'll see it returns exactly the same pin.

Comment: Post the contents of your `User` model.

Comment: method get_user add p User.find_by_pin(user.pin).to_sql , and look to the output

Comment: Returns an error: undefined method `to_sql' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What is the rails version that you use? This looks very strange - there might be some typo or something similar, since your code looks ok.

Comment: According to `rails -v` I'm using 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the problem was SQLite. For some reason it decided that it will not work properly.
I switched to MySQL and now everything works perfectly fine.